# While loop displays only 1 result

Tags: php

I am currently working on a search system and I want to display all rows that have 2 column names, problem is, my while loop only displays 1 row when I have 2 of them in the DB. I've been working my head around this for hours but I just can't get it. The only output I get is the last price.

```
<?php
include_once("inc/head.php");
include_once("inc/db.php");
$leave = $_POST['departure'];
$come = $_POST['destination'];
$leavedate = $_POST['leavedate'];
$comedate = $_POST['comedate'];
$sql = "select * from flights where departure = '$leave' and destination ='$come'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetchObject();
$price = $row->price;
$mostflights = $row->departure;
$mostcomings = $row->destination;
?>

<div>
    <ul class="flights">
        <?php
       while($row = $result->fetchObject())
        $price = $row->price;
        $mostflights = $row->departure;
        $mostcomings = $row->destination;
       { ?>

        <li>
            <h3><?php echo  $mostflights; ?></h3>
            <h2><?php echo  $mostcomings; ?></h2>
            <h2><?php echo  $price; ?></h2>
        </li>
        <?php
      }
  ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the result when you try your query manually in your dbms?

Comment: select * from flights where departure = '$leave' and destination ='$come' , if I replace the variables with the names I get from Post I get a successful query

Comment: why are you using `fetchObject()` twice?

Comment: because I am not so good at php yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this block at 10th line

```
$row = $result->fetchObject();
$price = $row->price;
$mostflights = $row->departure;
$mostcomings = $row->destination;
```

Comment: doing that gave the same result, I can still only see the price of the last row, If I remove the price variable, I can see the mostflights value and so on.

Comment: please move the first open curl `{` to right after while loop, like this `while($row = $result->fetchObject()) { `

Comment: That did it, I also just noticed what I was doing wrong.